# C# reset value in for loop(visual studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

```
int number =0;
int [,]   type = {{900, 750, 1020 },
                           {300, 1000, 2700 },
                           {500, 700, 2100 },
                           {400, 900, 1780 },
                           {600, 1200, 1100},
                           {575, 1150, 1900 },
                           {600, 1020, 1700 } };
int[] loot = {200,800,1100,600,900,300};enter code here
for (int row = 0; row < type.Get Length(0); row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < type.Get Length(1); column++)
    {
        first = type[row, column];

        for (int  i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {

            if (loot[i] ==first)
            {
                number++;
                Console.Waterline("print"+number);

            }//end if
            else
            {

            }//end else

        }//end for
```

I'm trying match value from type to loot, but i find the number is only accumulate after run it i want ask how do i reset the number to 0 every time run the for loop? it bother me a long time. Thanks for advice

Comment: Your code is not formatted properly

Comment: Are you trying to find where both array contain the same values?

Comment: thanks i fix number

Comment: yeah , Im trying to find both array contain the same values and print how many times every row of type have same value as loot. but trouble is number always add up to max.i want reset number to 0 every time run for loop (int  i = 0; i <= 5; i++)

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is type.Get Length(1) in the for loop supposed to do? Is that not spposed to be just type.length

Answer (score 1):

To find count of matches between loot items and items in multi-dimensional array:

```
int number = type.Cast<int>().Count(i => loot.Contains(i)); // 6
```

How it works:

Multi-dimensional array has an enumerator, which returns flattened items of array (see [Using foreach with Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3zzhdw.aspx)). Unfortunately that enumerator is not generic, so you have to cast items. After you get the sequence of all items in the multi-dimensional array, you can check whether loot array contains each item (and calculate count of such items).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I do find a way to match but how to reset number =0 for every time I run for (int  i = 0; i <= 5; i++) ....is still a problem i don't want add them all up..